# Можно ли использовать .dll MS Office через Java?

Tags: java, apache, dll, pdf, docx

Есть задача сконвертировать docx в pdf.
Разработка ведется на windows, но запускаться и работать должно на linux.
На linux нельзя использовать libre/open office.

Через apache POI работа выполняется некорректно, заполненные поля в форме пропадают при конвертации.

Возможно ли как то внедрить в свой проект dll MS Office?
Идея в том, чтоб использовать на linux конвертер doc4j, но ему нужен установленный MS Word.
Хочется сделать чтобы для работы doc4j не устанавливать MS Word, а использовать dll MS Office внутри проекта.
Но пока не понимаю как это сделать и можно ли вообще.

Comment: dll - это виндовая технология, у линукса несколько иначе. На linux длл не будет распознана и подключена. Тем более, что MSWord в программном исполнении это больше совокупность COM-объектов, а не просто набор функций, и далеко не в одной dll. COM - тоже виндовая технология.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий)

Comment: А может через uno?